# Canvas not scaling properly regardless to the set scalability

Tags: unity-game-engine, canvas, scalability

I'm trying to make my Canvas scalable regardless of screen size. I made it to be scalable across the screen but when it is hidden and called it is not scaled for some reason. I actually call it in code and it shows up when needed but it is not scalable but when I display it right away it is scalable.

**Expected position (is displayed normally when I do not hide the display):**
[image]

**Actual position (when my display is hidden and is displayed at the button pressing):**
[image]

How to make it scalable? I've searched for all possible solutions but I could not find an answer.

**These are the settings and hierarchy:**
[image]

**These are parent settings (main canvas):**
[image]

Comment: It would help to show any relevant code plus the canvas settings and hierarchy. Are you using a canvas scaler? What pivots and anchors are you using? What mode is the canvas in (overlay etc)?

Comment: @Absinthe I updated my canvas settings and hierarchy, check it out.

Comment: OK, so the first rect transform is a child of the main canvas? If so remove the canvas and canvas scaler on it. In the canvas scaler on your main canvas make sure to set the reference resolution to the resolution of the monitor you're actually using. Experiment with the screen match mode on that canvas scaler - you probably want to match width, based on the size and shape of your UI elements

Comment: I actually want the position which is in first image (expected position). Width and height are not the problem, as you can see in first settings tab the element should be positioned in bottom. But for some reason it ignores that position and it's not scalable.

Comment: Width and height on the canvas scaler refer to relative position as well as the size of the elements. Please just try the above suggestions and we can go from there :)

Comment: I tried and it's still the same, I set the screen size on 1920 x 1080 but the behavior is still identical as it was.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why CanvasScaller is not enough for you. I've never faced a case where I had to implement my own scalling, you should probably check CanvasScaller and use that, but anyway if your layout is not getting recalculated instantly you can force that by using

```
LayoutRebuilder.ForceRebuildLayoutImmediate(rectTransform);
```